# How to change the name of an installed package or a command in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I want to use gcc command as "abc". 
For example, I want to run the command "gcc program.c" as "abc program.c"

Comment: Why would you want to  do that? Renaming commands can sometimes be reasonable; renaming `gcc` as `abc` is not. An example of what you *really* want to do could make it easier to give you a useful answer.

Comment: From what i understand, you can use an alias : `alias gcc='abc'`
They are meant to create shortcut. `alias Target='What you want to rename [It works with options]'`